# Is it possible to extend a bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

The bounty I put on this question

[What is the Formula for Unit Maintenance in Civilization V?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8381/what-is-the-formula-for-unit-maintenance-in-civilization-v)

is due to expire in less than 24 hours.  There's some good work there, but nothing that yet really answers the question.  Is it possible to add more time, or should I just award it to the best answer that exists in 24 hours?

Comment: There is a workaround in which you can draw and reassign the bounty, but that would break the purpose of the bounty and cheat the system...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to add more time; the 7 days you get represents what you spent reputation on. Instead, you may add a new bounty once this one expires.

Think of bounties like a parking meter, except instead of having a fixed rate per time you pay whatever you want for a constant time period.

Comment: Can I monetize my rep to pay for some downtown parking?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with some cooperation.

Award the bounty to an answer that isn't yours and have the awardee start a bounty for the same amount of rep (or more!).

Comment: This is fine enough in small amounts. But if you catch 2 or more people continually doing this with each other to basically keep a question in "perpetual featured status", please report it as abuse with flags.